# How to integrate Azure Repo with AWS CodeCommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-codecommit, azure-repos

I want to implement `CI/CD` in `AWS CodeCommit`.

I know its possible manually to kickstart the process once the code reached CodeCommit. But I am using `Azure DevOps` Repo as my source code repo and want to automate the process.

The deployement is done using `AWS SAM`. I am looking for a method like; when I push a code to `Azure Repo` , it should reach the `AWS CodeCommit` and do the `CI/CD` without any further manual intervention.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: why would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure repos and CodeCommit are compliant with the git standard. The git standard allows you to specify multiple remotes. This is useful for if you were maintaining a mirror or, as in your use case, you need to do something in different environments.

You can read about setting multiple remotes [here](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242) (provided by github; even though you’re not using github the process and commands should be the same).

Once you have your multiple remotes setup, you can configure your CI/CD pipeline to kick off its process to deploy your SAM template based on your push; when you push your code changes they will be sent to both your Azure repo, and your CodeCommit repo, and your CI/CD pipeline that is monitoring your CodeCommit repo will see the change and kickoff its execution.

Its worth pointing out that you’ll need to properly setup and configure your CI/CD pipeline. AWS provides a number of services to support this including [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/), [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/), and [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/).

Comment: That was a good response. Thank you. But I am not using any third repo other than these two. All changes are committed to Azure Repo directly. What I am actually looking for is a mirror functionality in Azure Repo to link with AWS.

Comment: Your question says “when I push code to Azure repo, it should reach the AWS CodeCommit”, and now “looking for mirror functionality”. Both of these are exactly what is achieved by using multiple remotes. No third repo needed. Read the gist, it specifically mentions multiple remotes for mirrors. Instead of using github repos, as shown in the tutorial, just use your Azure and CodeCommit repos.